# Duplicating woocomerce products for other types of users does not work

Tags: woocommerce, duplicates, product, user-roles, frontpage

I created full permissions with the PublishPress Capabilities plugin. I tried to do this using the user role editor for the user "editor" Redaktor. When the user duplicates the product, he is redirected to the home page. The product does duplicate but no photos. That's why he has to go back to PA and upload the photos again. I have no idea how to fix it. I've tried many solutions but none fixes it. Do any of you have any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Popup Builder blocked that. I made downgrade this plugin. Now works fine